# How do I beat Beef Cloud?

Tags: mario-luigi-dream-team

Beef Cloud is sleeping his way through the battle, and is constantly regenerating health, seemingly faster than I can hit him!

How can I beat him?

Comment: find how he is regenerating and take that out?

Comment: He is regenerating because he is sleeping, and nothing wakes him up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Beef Clud is actually a quite easy boss to beat if you know how to do it correctly. The best method is to rapidly use your jump attack, and if you make two perfect jumps (Excellent), it should sometimes wake him up. Just keep using your jump attack over and over.

Answer (score 1):

The way to defeat him is almost impossible! I suggest you try to jump, use one of your strongest Luiginary powers and then get all EXCELLENTS. To use Luiginary powers, you need to eat Nuts and candies. That way, you get more of those shells.

Answer (score 0):

All right. There is a second way. And it includes POISON.

Find all of the mystery boxes. Then, use them all of them to defeat Beef Cloud. One of those boxes includes poison.

You could then die and use Easy Mode if you're on a low level. Step on Beef Cloud five or six times and he will be dead.

Answer (score -1):

You have to be quick and step on Beef Cloud about 5 to 8 times! Make sure Beef Cloud's HP doesn't increase too much. He will have a tiny bit of time waking up, so be ready to use your powers. Use your Luiginary Attacks wisely, because you can only use it once, and you can't lose. Good luck!